# Не обновляется размер яндекс карты при изменении width и height

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yandex-maps-api

Есть компонент, внутри которого компонент с Яндекс картой. Когда я меняю стили (через setState) в родительском компоненте, то все элементы верстки перерисовываются, кроме размеров вложенной карты. Поэтому она вылезает за границы блоков.

```
//MyComponent.js
import React from 'react';
import Map from './Map';
class MyComponent extands React.Component{
state = {style: {width: '500px'; height: '500px'}}
   render(){
    return (
       <div style = {this.state.style} onClick = {() => (this.setState({style: {width: '200px', height: '200px'}}))}>
         <Map/>
       </div>
    )}
}

// Map.js
import React from 'react';
class Map extands React.Component{
   render(){return (
      <div id='map' style={{height: '100%', weidth: '100%'}}/>
   )}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё, уже нагуглил)

При сложных перестроениях можно выставить автоматическое обновление карты при изменении размеров контейнера. При простых изменениях размера контейнера рекомендуется обновлять карту программно.

autoFitToViewport: 'always'

https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/fillcontainer